# Which property to use in Win32_PerfRawData_PerfProc_Process for indicating performance?

Tags: wmi, wmi-query

Inside the `Win32_PerfRawData_PerfProc_Process` class, which property is best describe the performance of the particular running service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what you mean by "performance of service". You could use **PercentProcessorTimeproperty**  to understand how much of processor time is consumed by the process.